# Check for [] operator

Tags: python

How do I check whether an object supports [] operation in Python? I think of something like the following:

```
if supports(obj, ?[]?):
    print("Supports")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `hasattr(obj, "__getitem__")`:

```
if hasattr(obj, "__getitem__"):
    print("Supports")
```

From the `operator.getitem` help:

```
operator.getitem??
Type:           builtin_function_or_method
Base Class:     <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:    <built-in function getitem>
Namespace:      Interactive
getitem(a, b) -- Same as a[b].
```

Check out the [operator module](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html):

> - Return the value of a at index b:
>
>   ```
>   operator.getitem(a, b)
>   operator.__getitem__(a, b)
>   ```
> - Return the slice of a from index b to index c-1:
>
>   ```
>   operator.getslice(a, b, c)
>   operator.__getslice__(a, b, c)
>   ```
> - Set the value of a at index b to c:
>
>   ```
>   operator.setitem(a, b, c)
>   operator.__setitem__(a, b, c)
>   ```
> - Set the slice of a from index b to index c-1 to the sequence v.
>
>   ```
>   operator.setslice(a, b, c, v)
>   operator.__setslice__(a, b, c, v)
>   ```
> - Remove the value of a at index b:
>
>   ```
>   operator.delitem(a, b)
>   operator.__delitem__(a, b)
>   ```
> - Delete the slice of a from index b to index c-1:
>
>   ```
>   operator.delslice(a, b, c)
>   operator.__delslice__(a, b, c)
>   ```

etc..

Answer (score 15):

You don't "check for support".  You just use it:

```
try:
    a = obj[whatever]
except TypeError:
    # whatever your fall-back plan is when obj doesn't support [] (__getitem__)
```

Writing your own `isinstance` is always the wrong thing to do.  A new type that doesn't inherit from the collections ABC classes can still have the right behavior.  Duck Typing means you can never rely on `isinstance`.

Writing your own `hasattr` test merely duplicates Python's internal checking that raises the exception.  Since Python **must** do the test, why duplicate that?

Finally, "I think that with exception handling this code will be less readable." Is false.  The Pythonic principle, accepted by many experienced Python programmers is that it's Easier to Ask Forgiveness That to Ask For Permission.

The language is designed to do this with exceptions.

Comment: +1. Generally speaking, I think it's more pythonic to ask for forgiveness than ask for permission.

Comment: I've thought about using this approach in the past, but I thought that catching things with exceptions was slower performing code. Is that not the case in Python?

Comment: Indeed, it's much nicer to avoid exceptions as they are quite expensive to raise.

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't be using Python if you're concerned about this tiny decrease in performance.  It's not quite a performant language compared to C (start flamewar here!).  Also... an `AttributeError` is definitely something you could get here instead of a `TypeError`.

Comment: Wow... I'm impressed. I've just run a set of tests, catching this through exceptions is *fast*. Faster than even testing for `__getitem__`'s negative case! I shall really have to rethink how I use exceptions in Python...

Comment: Exceptions are the least of your performance concern in Python, really. "Optimization" in Python consists mostly of choosing good data structures/algorithms (which should be your first step in every language!!!) and using things like list comprehensions so that at least the looping work can be done in native C. IIRC, native Python looping is often implemented in terms of exceptions anyway. If you're doing heavy numerical work, libraries like NumPy etc. are pretty much mandatory.

Comment: @AlbertPerrien I'd be interested to know what tests you ran -- I've seen lots of tests and unless the exception is pretty exceptional, it's generally slower -- even though performance is generally a side issue for things like this because it's just a micro-optimization.

Comment: "catching this through exceptions is fast".  Not an assumption.  A measurement.  Doesn't apply to Java.  Does apply to Python.  " I shall really have to rethink how I use exceptions".  Brilliant.  I had to rethink also when I saw similar measurements a few years back.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/p2fNkk1v) is the code I used to test. I'm guessing because of Python's interpreted nature, exceptions must be extraordinarily cheap. I'm going to have to rethink my code (and probably re-write some) in light of EAFP. Definitely learned something today.

Comment: Interesting. I get the opposite here (Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jun  4 2010, 18:20:31) 
[GCC 4.4.4 20100503 (Red Hat 4.4.4-2)] on linux2
), with exceptions taking twice the length of checking for `__getitem__`.

Comment: I need to check whether two objects are arrays or not, and if they are then I need to compare their elements. I think that with exception handling this code will be less readable.

Comment: @Max: "I think that with exception handling this code will be less readable".  If it's not an array, it doesn't have elements.  The exception demonstrates that perfectly clearly.  It's the pythonic approach.  It's the standard that Python programmers expect.  And.  Any test you contrive merely **attempts to duplicate** Python's internal checking that raises the exception.  Avoid duplication.  Avoid the possibility of getting the check wrong.

Comment: @Max: "I need to check whether two objects are arrays or not" indicates a deeper design problem that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The internal name of the `[]` operator is `__getitem__` (and `__setitem__`), so you can take a pretty good stab at this with:

```
if hasattr(obj, '__getitem__'):
    print "Supports"
```

Comment: If you care about that, yes. `tuple` doesn't support `__setitem__` or `__delitem__`, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if the class has an `__getitem__` method, as per the [language docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.4/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions).

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to see if you can iterate over an object (ie, do a `for i in obj`):

```
import collections
if isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable):
    print 'obj supports iteration'
```

If you're concerned about checking if you can use an actual key, I'd recommend just "asking for forgiveness" rather than permission:

```
try:
    value = obj[key]
except (AttributeError, TypeError, IndexError):
    # These are different things that can return in different situations
    value = None
    print 'I guess that key doesn\'t work'
```

The only reason I would suggest using `collections.Iterable` instead of this method is that having a `try` around your `for` loop around who knows what else, can get kind of complicated.

Comment: Being able to use the `[]` operator has _nothing_ to do with whether or not an object is iterable. You're looking for `collections.Sequence`, which is the equivalent of checking for `__getitem__`.

Comment: @agf, you're right of course, but I thought that was probably what the OP was trying to figure out (that's what I'm usually checking for).

Comment: If I was new to Python and asking about iteration, I might ask "How do I check if an object supports `in`" because that's how you first learn to iterate in Python, `for item in obj:`, not about `[]`, but I could see if you were still thinking in C syntax how that might make sense.