# Generic function to handle single element or sequence

Tags: python

I would like a generic function `get_me()` capable of handling both sequence and individual element arguments.

Code is below:

```py
from typing import Sequence

class class_1:
    def __init__(self, i: int=0):
        self.name = 'A'+str(i)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class class_2:
    def __init__(self, i: int=0):
        self.name = 'B'+str(i)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

def get_me(seq: Sequence):

    for s in seq:
        print(f"\n1 is {s[0].name}, 2 is {s[1].name}")
```

This works for all the following combinations:

```
one = class_1(1), class_2(1)
two = class_1(2), class_2(2)
three = class_1(3), class_2(3)

many = [one, two, three]
many = (one, two, three)
many = {one, two}
many = one, two

get_me(many)
```

... but gives a `TypeError` for

> get_me(one)

Is it possible to have this code handle it, without a `try: except` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for \[\] operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604380/check-for-operator)

Comment: @fountainhead: 

```def get_me(seq: Union[Sequence, Tuple]):
    if hasattr(seq, '__getitem__'):
        for s in seq:
            print(f"\n1 is {s[0].name}, 2 is {s[1].name}")
    else:
        print(f"\n1 is {s[0].name}, 2 is {s[1].name}")``` still gives error for get_me(one)

Comment: In your `else` clause, you should not be using the `[]` operator at all.

Comment: @fountainhead: ... but `one[0].name, one[1].name` works....So, what could be put instead?

Comment: The way you've written it, in the `else` clause, `s` is undefined (in the `if` clause, `s` is defined by the `for` loop). That is probably why you are getting the error in the `else` clause. So, in the `else` clause, you should be printing `seq[0].name` and `seq[1].name`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you are after:

```
from typing import Sequence, Union, Tuple

# ...

def get_me(seq: Union[Sequence, Tuple]):
    if isinstance(seq, tuple):
        seq = (seq,)
    for s in seq:
        print(f"\n1 is {s[0].name}, 2 is {s[1].name}")
```

This relies on the individual element being a tuple, as it is in your example - but so does your `print` statement, so that seems reasonable. If you need it to work for any type, you could replace it with `Any` and check that it's not a sequence - but of course you'd have to amend the `print` statement as well, as well as any other code using the parameter.

You noted that this solution doesn't work when you define `many` as:

```
many = one, two
```

That's correct, since this makes many a `Tuple` as well.

To support that as well, you'd want something like:

```
def get_me(seq: Sequence):
    if not isinstance(seq[0], tuple):
        seq = (seq,)
    for s in seq:
        print(f"\n1 is {s[0].name}, 2 is {s[1].name}")
```

However, that's not as strict or explicit. Another approach would be:

```
class SuperClass:
    pass


class Class1(SuperClass):
    # ...


class Class2(SuperClass):
    # ...


# ... 


def get_me(seq: Union[Sequence[SuperClass], SuperClass]):
    if isinstance(seq, SuperClass):
        seq = (seq,)
    for s in seq:
        print(f"\n1 is {s[0].name}, 2 is {s[1].name}")
```

Which is the solution I'd prefer, if all the explicit typing is a requirement.

Comment: This works for get_me(one), but fails with an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'` for get_me(many).

Comment: I've updated the answer to take the `many` as a tuple into account, and provided a perhaps preferable solution. (note that I renamed your `class_1` to `Class1`, which is following Python naming conventions for classes)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `try: except` cannot be avoided, while keeping the code simple, due to various possible permutations of argument types.

So the code...

```py
def get_me(seq: Sequence):

    try:
        for s in seq:
            print(f"\n1 is {s[0].name}, 2 is {s[1].name}")
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):
        print(f"\n1 is {seq[0].name}, 2 is {seq[1].name}")
```

...works for all my possible cases:

```py
one = class_1(1), class_2(1)
two = class_1(2), class_2(2)
three = class_1(3), class_2(3)

many = [one, two, three]
many = (one, two, three)
many = {one, two}
many = one, two

get_me(many)
get_me(one)
get_me(two)
get_me(three)
```

Comment: The `print` that you have now in the `except` clause, is what you should have used in the `else` part of `if hasattr()`. (See my last comment beneath your question)